# .wheel event | Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using js function to slow down scroll frequency, the chrome gives the following error:

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.

```js
    var scrollTimeout = 1;
    var throttle = 4500;
    var scrollMessage = function (message) {
        console.log(message);
    
    };
    
    $(window).bind('wheel', function () {
        if (scrollTimeout === 0) {
            return false;
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('Throttled scroll');
                scrollTimeout = 1;
            }, throttle);
        } else {
            scrollTimeout = 0;
            console.log('native scroll');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Whats the possible solution to get this to work.

Comment: Hi, besides the `return false` being in the wrong position (should be below the `setTimeout`; what is not working for you?

Comment: I tried it but i get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome [doesn't like](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312) custom wheel events on *top level elements* and ignores them if not specifically set to active. jQuery doesn't allow you to set those [event properties](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2871) yet.

I've reverted to using vanilla JavaScript which allows you to set the passive flag to `false` on the event options.

I've put an event object `e` into the function, allowing to use [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). Replaced the `return false` below the `setTimeout` so I doesn't immediately exits the function. It - based - on your code function properly now.

```js
var scrollTimeout = 1;
var throttle = 4500;
var scrollMessage = function(message) {
  console.log(message);

};

//since jQuery doesn't allow you to set the event's property to passive = false yet, revert to vanilla

document.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  //added e as reference for the event object
  
  if (scrollTimeout === 0) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Throttled scroll');
      scrollTimeout = 1;
    }, throttle);
    e.preventDefault(); //cancelling default action
    return false; // return false for safety
  } else {
    scrollTimeout = 0;
    console.log('native scroll');
  }
}, { passive: false });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```